# Bad characters showing up when executing python script in Bash

Tags: python, bash, character

I was executing a python script through a Bash terminal, and the output of the script suddenly became in bad characters like "IOE⎼⎼⎺⎼: [E⎼⎼┼⎺ 2]" Now when I try typing in the terminal it gives me "┌⎽" for "ls" for example. If I open a new terminal, it's fine but whenever I run that script it's a problem. I can't find anything in the script that would do this. Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Your script sent the escape sequence to switch to the alternate character set.

Comment: I can't find anywhere in the script where this happens. is there a way to just stop this from happening, either at the python or bash level?

Comment: bash isn't involved when your script is running. It just starts the script when you type the python command.

Comment: Python just prints what the script tells it to print. It doesn't know which characters have special meaning to the terminal. So there's no way to tell it not to print them.

Comment: You could use `script` to save terminal output to a file while running the script. Then you can check the file to see what was sent when it switched to this mode, and look for that in the script.

Comment: There are a bunch of escape sequences and/or control codes that'll invoke an alternate character set. Usually, this happens as a result of binary gibberish being sent to the terminal (that happens to have sequences in it that trigger an alternate character set), so check the output of that Python script. To get the terminal back to normal, try `tput reset`, or if that doesn't work try `printf '\ec'`.